# onClick event not working on click of DatePicker icon of Microsoft React fabric

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, ms-office, office-js

I am trying to show the error message onClick event of DatePicker. But it is working when we click on the datepicker input box. But when we are clicking on datepicker icon, onClick event not working.
Can anyone please suggest any event to show the warning message on click of icon as well.

I am using below component:

```
import { DatePicker } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';

<div className="date-range">
                <DatePicker
                    label={text.label}
                    placeholder={text.placeholder}
                    id={text.id}
                    showMonthPickerAsOverlay
                    strings={DayPickerStrings}
                    onSelectDate={date => onDateRangeChange(date, text.id)}
                    onClick={event => onDateChangeClick(event)}
                    isMonthPickerVisible={false}
                    formatDate={date => onFormatDate(date, pattern)}
                    minDate={minDate}
                    maxDate={maxDate}
                    value={value[text.id]}
                />
                {showEndDateWarning ? (
                    <p className="warningClass">{text.warningMsg}</p>
                ) : null}
            </div>
```

Comment: Code looks incomplete.

Comment: yes... I know.. I pasted only required code. onClick event function is working fine and changing the state value "showEndDateWarning" to true and I am able to see the warning message. But onClick of DatePicker icon this onDateChangeClick function not called.

Comment: please refer this link for my DatePicker component: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/datepicker

Answer (score 0):

you can change the state value of "showEndDateWarning" to true on  "onSelectDate" event.

Comment: I want that state value  of "showEndDateWarning" to true while click on DatePicker, not after changing the date from DatePicker. in your suggestion, I can show the warning message after date change. I want it on Click event of anywhere on datepicker whether it is input box of datepicker or icon of datepicker.

Comment: please refer this link for my DatePicker component: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/datepicker

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue and resolved it by using onClickCapture=

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
    DatePicker,
    IDatePickerStrings,
    defaultDatePickerStrings,
    IDatePickerStyles
} from '@fluentui/react';
import { useConst } from '@fluentui/react-hooks';
import { AcknowledgementReIssueResponse } from '../models/dtos';

// START COMPONENT
const datePickerStyles: Partial<IDatePickerStyles> = { root: { maxWidth: 200, marginTop: -10 } };
export const ReIssueOnPicker = (props: { acknowledgementReIssueResponse: AcknowledgementReIssueResponse, disabled: boolean, onPress: (controlName : string ) => void }) => {
    console.log('ReIssueOnPicker');
    console.log(props);

    const minDate = new Date(props.acknowledgementReIssueResponse.dueFrom);
    const zeroPad = (num, places) => String(num).padStart(places, '0')

    const onSelectDate = React.useCallback(
        (date: Date): void => {
            // toISODate applied browser local time offset ?
            props.acknowledgementReIssueResponse.reIssueOn = `${date.getFullYear()}-${zeroPad(date.getMonth() + 1, 2)}-${zeroPad(date.getDate(), 2)}T00:00:00.0000000`;
        }, null
    );

    const strings: IDatePickerStrings = useConst(() => ({
        ...defaultDatePickerStrings,
    }));

    return (
        <div>
            <DatePicker
                styles={datePickerStyles}
                // DatePicker uses English strings by default. For localized apps, you must override this prop.
                onSelectDate={onSelectDate}
                onAfterMenuDismiss={() => props.onPress('')}
                **onClickCapture**={event => props.onPress('ReIssueOnPicker')}
                disabled={props.disabled}                 
                strings={strings}
                placeholder="Select a date..."
                ariaLabel="Select the date to re-issue on"
                minDate={minDate}
                allowTextInput
                value={minDate}
                />
        </div>
    );
};
```